# Linux: killing python script which executes bash command

Tags: python, bash, mpi

I have a python routine `python.py` which basically writes a command string contained in the file `Command_text.txt` and launches it from terminal, executing:

`command = 'bash Command_text.txt'
os.system(command)`

Now, the command contained in the `Command_text.txt` is `mpirun` which launches a series of *parallel python scripts*. Now, if i launch the `python.py` routine from the shell I can simply kill it pressing `Ctrl+C`. If I use the command `nohup python.py &` the situation is more complicated as if I `ps` my processes I need to find and kill the ones with CMD `python` `bash` and `mpirun` to definitely kill all the job (which means all the following parallel python computations), as shown in the image below:

[image]

Now my question is: is there a way to kill the `python.py` original process automatically killing afterwards the relative `bash` and `mpirun` ones as when pressing `Ctrl+C`?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: I've previously used the `signal` module to 'listen' for SIGKILL or SIGTERM signals from the command line and then run some code if these signals are received such as `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)`, this may help as a starting point?

Comment: This question is somewhat duplicated but I read it as, when I press `Ctrl+C` in Python, can I also kill the child processes automatically... and that is not answered in the dupe?